# como extraer URLS de una cadena de texto con NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito extraer links de un archivo que se encuentra en formato Markdown, estoy trabajando con NodeJs. No se cual método emplear.

Explico un poco lo que estoy haciendo: valido las rutas, si es relativa convierto en absoluta, luego valido que sea un archivo, filtro solo los archivos **(.md)** y leo su contenido.

Ahora bien, necesito extraer de ese contenido solo los links que se encuentren alli. pero estoy bloqueada, no se como hacerlo. ayuda plis!

Este es mi código

```
const fs = require ('fs');
const path = require ('path'); 

const pathExists = function(ruta) {
   return fs.existsSync(ruta)
} 

const pathIsAbsolute = function(ruta){
  return path.isAbsolute(ruta)
} 

const convertPathInAbsolute = function(ruta){
  if (path.isAbsolute(ruta)){
    return ruta
  }else{
    return path.resolve(ruta)
  }
}
const pathIsDirectory = (ruta) => {
  return fs.lstatSync(ruta).isDirectory()
}
const pathIsFile = function (ruta){
  return fs.statSync(ruta).isFile()
}

const readDirectoryandFile = (ruta) => {
  if(pathIsDirectory(ruta)){
    const arrayD = fs.readdirSync(ruta) 
    const arrayMd = arrayD.filter(archivo => 
      path.extname(archivo) ===".md"); 
    const arrayFmd = fs.readFileSync("./personal.md", "UTF-8") 
  }else{
    const arrayF = fs.readFileSync("./personal.md", "UTF-8")
} 
}
console.log/(readDirectoryandFile(process.argv[2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con una expresion regular como la siguiente

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

o [get-urls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-urls)

```
require('get-urls')(`${texto}`)
```

Comment: gracias. Me podrias ayudar Como seria la funcion para extraer los links y guardarlos en un array